# The polling time is not recorded in response time

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

The polling time is not recorded in response time how can I do that below is my scenario

I send a request every 500ms to a server to see if the result for the query is available( this is known by status as completed) when the status is completed I send another request to fetch result

Problem: the pooling time is not captured as part of the response time. so If I waited for 5 min(polled for 5 min) to get the result then this should be added to response time as the user will to see this added response time when he uses the system from a UI

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your request and polling in a group and set useGroupDurationMetric in gatling.conf to true

Answer (score 0):

It will be if you start your timer before the looping structure and end it when you have your final result.

We have been doing this is LoadRunner for the better part of a two decades while a web client polls every n seconds for a report to complete.

PCODE

```
 start_timer(timer name)

 do
 {
      sleep ( some seconds or milliseconds)
      Check Report Status for done
 } while (not done)

 stop_timer(timer name)
```